# Access Denied error in python when trying to remove directory

Tags: windows, python-3.x, directory, access-denied

I'm trying to remove some directorys from my desktop.

The name of the directorys follow the format year+month (Ex.: 201808), i need to remove the directorys 2+ months before (Ex.: 201705, 201709, 201806).

Using the `os.remove(path)`, the python return a error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\teste.py", line 36, in <module>
    os.remove(caminhoPastaFinal)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado: 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Área de testes\\pasta1\\pasta2\\pasta3\\pasta4\\201712'
```

I tried to run the script as admin in the CMD, but i got the same error.
I'm using Windows 10.

Why i don't have permission to do that?

Follow the code:

```
import os
from datetime import *

def verificarNome(nomePasta):
    mes=nomePasta[-2:]
    ano=nomePasta[:-2]
    if ano<anoAtual:
        return True
    elif mes<=mesAtual:
        return True
    return False


dataAtual = datetime.now()
anoAtual = str(dataAtual.year)
mesAtual = dataAtual.month
if mesAtual < 10:
    mesAtual = "0"+str(mesAtual-2)
else:
    mesAtual = str(mesAtual-2)

caminhoPai = 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Área de testes'

for caminhoPasta in os.listdir(caminhoPai): #Logo farei uma função recursiva que diminua esse código, mas ainda tenho que estudá-las
    caminhoFilho1 = caminhoPai+"\\"+caminhoPasta
    for caminhoPasta2 in os.listdir(caminhoFilho1):
        caminhoFilho2 = caminhoFilho1+"\\"+caminhoPasta2
        for caminhoPasta3 in os.listdir(caminhoFilho2):
            caminhoFilho3 = caminhoFilho2+"\\"+caminhoPasta3
            for caminhoPasta4 in os.listdir(caminhoFilho3):
                caminhoFilho4 = caminhoFilho3+"\\"+caminhoPasta4
                arrayPastasVerificar = os.listdir(caminhoFilho4)
                for pastaFinal in arrayPastasVerificar:
                    if verificarNome(pastaFinal): 
                        caminhoPastaFinal = caminhoFilho4+"\\"+pastaFinal
                        os.remove(caminhoPastaFinal)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

month = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
oneMonthBefore= (month - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)
twoMonthBefore= (oneMonthBefore - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1)

root = 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Directorys'

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for dir in dirs[:]:
        try:
            dirDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dir, '%Y%m')
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if dirDate < twoMonthBefore:
            dirs.remove(dir)
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(path, dir))
```